# Suppress Scientific Format in a Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scientific-notation

I have a column called accountnumber with values similar to 4.11889000e+11 in a pandas dataframe. I want to suppress the scientific notation and convert the values to 4118890000. I have tried the following method and did not work.

```
df = pd.read_csv(data.csv)
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format
```

Please recommend.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume the exponential notation for the account numbers must come from the data file. If I create a small csv with the full account numbers, pandas will interpret them as integers.

```
     acct_num
0  4118890000
1  9876543210

df['acct_num'].dtype
Out[51]: dtype('int64')
```

However, if the account numbers in the csv are represented in exponential notation then pandas will read them as floats.

```
       acct_num
0  4.118890e+11
1  9.876543e+11

df['acct_num'].dtype
Out[54]: dtype('float64')
```

You have 2 options. First, correct the process that creates the csv so the account numbers are written out correctly. The second is to change the data type of the acct_num column to integer.

```
df['acct_num'] = df['acct_num'].astype('int64')

df
Out[66]: 
       acct_num
0  411889000000
1  987654321000
```

Answer (score 16):

You don't need the thousand separators "," and the 3 decimals for the account numbers.

Use the following instead.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format
```

Comment: yes, this works, when I just print df.Accountnumber it displays converted values. However, when I print df.Accountnumber.unique(), it still shows all values in exponential format.

Comment: In this case, you need to change the data type of account number column , as proposed by @floydn .

Comment: you could also change the print format, this solution is better as the original datatype is still valid

Answer (score 0):

#Use this
pd.set_option("display.float_format", lambda x: "%.2f" % x)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).