# How to get h2o to return results in non-scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas, h2o

I wrote python code to return the count of each levels of a feature of a h2o dataframe, but the result always come back in scientific notation.  How do I get it to display using decimal?

Code I used:

```
print(all_propensity["HasLoss"].table())
```

What it returns:

HasLoss       Count

0                        1.46457e+07

1                         35277

What I want it to return:

HasLoss       Count

0                        14,645,700

1                         35,277

Answer (score 1):

In R you would use `options(digits=12)`, or something like that, to not have it use scientific precision until that number of digits. But in Python there seems no way to override the global default (which I think is 6 digits), and all the answers I found were about doing the formatting yourself.

But you can control it in ipython/Jupyter with:

```
%precision 12
```

(See https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-precision )

Or, assuming you have pandas imported, the table H2O returns is actually a pandas table, so there are formatting options there. I think `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format` would do it.  Or change the column data type to an int64, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49910142/841830

All the options for pandas are here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options or search for pandas ways to format data. (I.e. just remember that H2O gives you a pandas data set, so it is a pandas question once you have the data in python.)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I ended up converting it to panda frame and used the display format.