# Merge CSV files in a Pandas Dataframes based on a Text Field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, merge

I have two csv files I am trying to merge into one data frame using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.read_csv('A.csv')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('B.csv')
df_3 = df_1.merge(df_2, on='Material_Number_ID', how='left')
```

The field I am trying to use to merge them on (Material_Number_ID) is a 12 digit number that gets converted to a text field when I save it as a csv.  This is preventing me from using that field as the link because it doesn't recognize the the numbers are different.

```
Dataframe A:
  Material_Number_ID   Material_Type
0        4.920000e+11  FINISHED GOODS
1        4.920000e+11  FINISHED GOODS

Dataframe B:
   Material_Number_ID    Merch_Org
0        4.920000e+11  ACCESSORIES

Output:  
 Material_Number_ID   Material_Type    Merch_Org
0        4.920000e+11  FINISHED GOODS  ACCESSORIES
1        4.920000e+11  FINISHED GOODS  ACCESSORIES
```

The problem is that row 1 should not find a match because, at the 12th digit of the original number, the Material_Number_IDs are different.

Expected Output is

```
 Material_Number_ID   Material_Type    Merch_Org
0        4.920000e+11  FINISHED GOODS  ACCESSORIES
1        4.920000e+11  FINISHED GOODS  NaN
```

I know the answer is in chaning the material number id somehow but I don't know the right method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909710/suppress-scientific-format-in-a-dataframe-column), when you import from the csv pandas reads the numbers as floats. If you convert them to int64 using the following code, it should display all numbers of the `Material_Number_ID`.

```
df_1['Material_Number_ID'] = df_1['Material_Number_ID'].astype('int64')
df_2['Material_Number_ID'] = df_2['Material_Number_ID'].astype('int64')
```